# Webpack not properly compiling (Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I've been struggling with this issue for a few days now, and I can't tell what the problem is exactly. Basically, what's bothering me here is the following warning: `WARNING in ./node_modules/colors/lib/colors.js  141:29-43 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression`. It causes my app to crash/not properly work.

I can make the other errors go away (such as `ERROR in ./config/internals/environmentVars.js
 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/app/config/internals'`) by adding a line in my webpack config, but I cannot get rid of the first one. Any help on this topic will be greatly appreciated! I can provide you with more code if you need it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem compiling a node application. Solved placing in the **webpack.config** file the **target** option.

```
target: 'node'
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for answering. I already saw & tried this solution before, and it did not work for me.